# css files of widgets not being downloaded in themeroller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

When downloading jquery-ui from ThemeRoller and the Widgets button is checked, I don't see any css files belonging to those widgets (as well as the other objects) in the download.

I picked the "Blitzer" theme, and don't see anything in regards to it in the files downloaded.

The files I have are comprised of the following:

An "external" folder which has a jquery.js file.

An "images" folder.

A "jquery-ui.js" file. Several "jquery-ui", theme, structure css    files.

Are these the correct files for the download?

Comment: They are included within one of the js files

Comment: I see that they are now included in the jquery-ui.js file... Apparantly, they have taken a lot of the css files out and just included them in the theme css and jquery ui js files.

Comment: Yeah gets a bit heavy you know? Besides the modernizer js and all backs you up when user browser don't have necessary tools. :)